# Android Studio Gradle Build Errors

Tags: java, android

```
private void reorderSpinners() {
    char[] order = DateFormat.getDateFormatOrder(getContext());
    final int spinnerCount = order.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < spinnerCount; i++) {
        switch (order[i]) {
            case DateFormat.DATE:
                pushSpinner(daySpinner, spinnerCount, i);
                break;
            case DateFormat.MONTH:
                pushSpinner(monthSpinner, spinnerCount, i);
                break;
            case DateFormat.YEAR:
                pushSpinner(yearSpinner, spinnerCount, i);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

cannot find symbol variable DATE
cannot find symbol variable MONTH
cannot find symbol variable YEAR

Comment: Check the document for available options : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

> cannot find symbol variable DATE cannot find symbol variable MONTH cannot find symbol variable YEAR

That is because those symbols do not exist on `DateFormat`. You can tell that by [reading the documentation for `DateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html).

Comment: I read that document already.. couldn't help myself
If you can tell which symbols to use ?

Comment: @AshishAggarwal: AFAIK, there are no symbols. [The documentation for `getDateFormatOrder()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getDateFormatOrder%28android.content.Context%29) does not indicate that any of the three characters (`'d'`, `'M'`, `'y'`) have definitions as `static` fields anywhere.